# Lotus Notes document fields missing while 'parent' form is open

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I've been developing in Lotus (IBM) Notes/domino for something like 25 years and I've never come across this before.

The application is Notes client based, using Notes 9.

I open a document (DOC A) , which uses FORM A. From this document, there is a button to create a new document which uses FORM B. This opens in a new window. DOC B is not a response of DOC A, but some (a lot) of LotusScript copies fielse from DOC A to DOC B.

So now we have 3 windows open: The original application, the DOC A doc and the DOC B.

I make edits to DOC B, and save it. I close it, leave DOC A open, and navigate to another view where DOC B can be found.

Interrogate the Document Properties field list to see the field I edited ("InvoiceComments" in my case). Yep, my text is there.

Then I run a script agent which gets DOC B and prints up the content of InvoiceComments. It's blank. Write a Web agent to get same doc ... my text can be found in InvoiceComments.

It's definitely the same document, same UNID etc.

So that is: When looking at Document Properties, fields list, I can see myy edits in the field values. When running a script via Notes Client to get that document (either via UnprocessedDocument or from a view), the field has its 'old' value (blank)

The only clue I have as to what's going on is that if I close the DOC A, then all of a sudden the agent that prints "InvoicComments" value starts to honour what's on the disk (ie, it behaves).

Sounds like a  bug in the notes client, but I'm at a loss as to how to get around it because people will want to do the process above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this some time ago when working with big script libraries and global variables.

I needed a LOT of debugging to find out what was wrong.

Essentially the problem is: As long as there is a variable ANYWHERE in the code that holds the document Doc A, then any script -run from whatever context- will get the "old" values of that document (despite the frontend showing you the changed item value).

Either Delete the NotesDocument- Object holding doc A in any code from doc B or use Set .... = Nothing to prevent that from happening.

So using either of these two lines will help:

```
Delete docA
Set docA = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!     Ah yes, I've been caught out by that many times - however this is (I think) slightly different in that the routines which hold a handle on that document (DOC A or DOC B) have all finished, so the object would (should) be garbage-coillected.. sounds like to be this issue, an object referring to DOC B would need to still be in memory, probably in the form of DOC A ? (hope this makes sense). I'll try setting it to nothing at the end of the routine in case this is a garbage collection bug

Comment: I tried hard to reproduce and sometimes the documents where not garbage collected as long as there was an object holding the DATABASE object where the document was in... try to delete that as well...

Comment: I added a Delete Line at the end of the routine whcih created DOC B to destry it (should get destroyed anyway as it's the end of the routine, and the notesdocument was local to that rouitne).. IT WORKED ! Thanks very much for your prompt answer

Comment: I searched about one week to find out about that issue... since then i delete almost every object... nice to hear that this simple tipp helped you...

Comment: "Delete" is also very helpful when iterating over large document collections or views (Delete when done with current doc) else your run out of memory

Answer (score 1):

I can't take credit for this code, a consultant wrote it, but maybe this pattern will fix your problem:

```
Set doc=uidoc.Document
newentry=doc.CommentEntry(0)
id=doc.Universalid
Call uidoc.Fieldclear("CommentEntry") 
Call uidoc.Save
Call uidoc.Close(True)
Set doc=db.GetDocumentByUNID(id)
doc.CommentEntry=newentry
```

He found that even when you have a "valid" document object with a valid UNID, when you have it open as a UiDoc, Notes (frustratingly) keeps a copy in memory, so he had to resort to this idea.  (Is it a bug or just a quirk?)  I think this is essentially what Torsten is suggesting as well.

Comment: Thanks Duston- at least I have somethign to try now :-)